# Get custom attribute value without loading the product

Tags: event-observer, performance

I'm trying to get custom product attribute value (for attribute code `flr01`) in `catalog_product_save_after` observer without loading the product but I'm gettin null value if I'm not loading the product before using following functions

```
$qty = $observer->getProduct()->getAttributeText('flr01');
```

or

```
$qty = $observer->getProduct()->getData('flr01');
```

While loading the product before using `getData()` method, I'm getting `flr01` value

```
$productId = $observer->getProduct()->getId();
$product = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$qty = $product->getData('flr01');
```

I think loading the product again is not recommended from performance point of view (I should already have all product attributes available in `$observer->getProduct()` ).

Comment: have you try this: `$product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get custom attribute data using below code at observer

```
$observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getData('flr01')
```

**and for getting : text value if it dropdown.**

```
    $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('flr01')
->getFrontend()->getValue‌​($observer->getEvent()->getProduct());
```

Comment: can you help on this question ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/362942/magento-2-is-it-impact-on-isting-page-performance-for-product-getresource

Answer (score 10):

To retrieve a single attribute directly from the database, you can use

```
$flr01 = $product->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue(
    $product->getId(),
    'flr01',
    Mage::app()->getStore()
);
```

If you need multiple attributes, you can also pass an array of attribute codes instead of a single attribute code, then the result is an array in the form `[attribute_code => attribute_value]`.

#### Example:

```
$attributes = $product->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue(
    $product->getId(),
    ['flr01', 'flr02', 'flr03'],
    Mage::app()->getStore()
);

// Now you have the values in:
$attributes['flr01'];
$attributes['flr02'];
$attributes['flr03'];
```

Note that this will return you the *raw value*, i.e. if the attribute is not a simple text field attribute, but uses a dropdown, multiselect or a custom backend model, the `attribute->getFrontend()` method described by [@Amit Bera](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/75245/243) will give you the formatted value as it gets displayed.

Comment: Can you give one example of fetching multiple attributes using above method? say flr01, flr02,flr03.

Comment: See example in updated answer