# magento 2 : is it impact on isting page performance for $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_attribute_code')?

Tags: magento2.4, performance, magento-product-attributes

I have a custom attribute which has 15 text values.
I am using `$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attributecode)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);` . In catalog page I have used above code get the text value of attribute for every product in for loop, is it impacted on performance ? Above code everytime call in database to get the attribute optiontext ?

Answer (score 0):

In your product/list.phtml you should have access to the custom attribute through a simple

```
<?php echo $_product->getCustomAttributeCode() ?>
```

Remember to set your custom attribute "Used in Product Listing"

Comment: thank you for answer, but I am not asking for how to get customattribute from product object, please update your answer

Comment: Hi Niraj, maybe I didn't understand the question, but taking the attribute directly from the object passed by the collection I would say you solve any doubts about the performance.

Comment: my question is if we use $_product->getCustomAttributeCode() code in for loop and for loop iterates 10 times so above code hits in database 10 times to get attribute text ?

Answer (score 0):

We normally use this for printing labels in options attributes, which may *seem lighter* than posted code

```
$_product->getAttributeText($attributecode);
```

But if we check what this does we can see

```
public function getAttributeText($attributeCode)
{
    return $this->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode)->getSource()->getOptionText(
        $this->getData($attributeCode)
    );
}
```

Which seems practically the same as posted code, so I don't think you could find a better approach in terms of performance, apart from getting the value you want directly with a SQL query which would be obviously the lightest & fastest approach

Comment: my question is if we use $_product->getAttributeText($attributecode) code in for loop and for loop iterates 10 times so above code hits in database 10 times to get attribute text ?

Comment: Not sure how much calls would result, you can use Magento profiler & see :)